# F# filtering a tree

Tags: f#, tree, filtering

I want to make function that will let me filter tree but it dont return all elements matching predicate.

```
type Tree = 
    | Empty
    | Element of float * Tree * Tree
let rec filter predicate = 
        function
        | Empty -> Empty
        | Element(a,b,c) when predicate(a) 
            -> Element(a, filter predicate b, filter predicate c)
        | Element(_,b,c) -> filter predicate b
                            filter predicate c
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what the function would return? is the tree a search tree?

Comment: New tree witch elements that matches predicate

Comment: ok, didnt u ask a question about delete? I think its basically the same issue

Comment: The last branch makes no sense. You are discarding `filter predicate b` and only returning `filter predicate c`. Does this even compile? There is no `ignore` for the first line i.e. `filter predicate b |> ignore` . Not able to check if this compiles right now but does not look correct. You need the parent element to return a new Element i.e. the last branch should be something like  `| Element(a,b,c) -> Element(parent a, filter predicate b, filter predicate c)` . How you determine `parent` is to be decided.

Comment: @BartolinioKooperinio - as Martin says, the above implementation simply throws away one result "filter predicate b". If you have the delete function you have written you can use that as a starting point

Comment: Yup, we need to see your `delete` function. This question has insufficient detail. If it does not compile, let's see the errors. If it does, we need to see test data and the results. Hence my downvote until then.

Answer (score 1):

Theres three cases you have to consider when deleting a node from a binary tree.

1. when the deleted node has no children: This one is easy, we just skip it when constructing the result.
2. when deleted node has exactly one child: This one involves placing the child in the place of the deleted node.
3. when deleted node has two or more children: Here we need to consider if your tree has any special ordering such as the case of a binary search tree. If theres no considerations needed, just bring up any one of the children to the place of the deleted node.

Heres a similar answer for Haskell
[delete node from binary search tree, haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626132/delete-node-from-binary-search-tree-haskell)